# Recovering from database downtime with streaming data

Tags: sql-server, recovery

I have a situation where I receive a continuous stream of data. This data gets processed and transferred into a database (SQL Server).

Now, I'm trying to code a model where if the db is down, the data is 'saved' locally (say in a file) -- and flushed out to the db when it recovers.

I was wondering if there are any existing better designed programming models for solving this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "proper" way to deal with that is to use [Failover Clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx) so if a DB server drops off, another takes over. Obviously that's a major (expensive) endeavor so your solution of spooling data to disk is a good alternative if it fits your need.